# Using EF to return specific formatted JSON from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, linq, entity-framework

I have a model like below where **PermissionGroup has 1-Many relationship with Permission** and **Permission and Roles have Many-Many relationship**.

```
PermissionGroup 1-----* Permission *--------* Role
```

I have to be able to return JSON in the following format:

```
PermissionGroupId : 1,
PermissionGroupName : "Market",
Permissions : [
 {PermissionId : 1, PermissionName : "Create"},
 {PermissionId : 2, PermissionName : "Update"}
]
```

That will be asked for a specific `RoleId`.

**Problem:**

Since, `PermissionGroup` has no relation directly with `Role` so I cannot do a `Where` linq query. I could do the following but it is not returning desired result like above.

```
public JsonResult GetRolePermission(int roleid)
{
    var list = con.PermissionGroups.Select(pg => new
    {
        PermissionGroupId = pg.PermissionGroupId,
        PermissionGroupName = pg.PermissionGroupName,
        Permissions = pg.Permissons.Select(pe => new
        {
            PermissionId = pe.PermissionId,
            PermissionName = pe.PermissionName
        }) 
    })//Maybe do the where query here somehow like where(f => f.RoleId == roleid);

    return Json(list);
}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Your json doesn't have any `Roles` member. Is it full? And what is `roleid`? How it is connected with `PermissionGroups`?

Comment: @Tony Thanks for your comment. Yes it does not and it is full JSON spec. I could not think of anything else at the time. So, I experimented with what I had in mind. `RoleId` is primary identifier for the `Role` entity. Please refer to the diagram I posted above for their relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method in `Where`? Like this:

```
var list = con.PermissionGroups
    .Where(pg => pg.Permissons.Any(p => p.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == roleId)))
    .Select(pg => new
    {
        PermissionGroupId = pg.PermissionGroupId,
        PermissionGroupName = pg.PermissionGroupName,
        Permissions = pg.Permissons.Select(pe => new
        {
            PermissionId = pe.PermissionId,
            PermissionName = pe.PermissionName
        })
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. But I think I was not able to explain to you properly before. Please take a look at the revised question again.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this but highly doubt that it is efficient.

```
var getPermissionsForRole = context.Roles.Where(roleid => roleid.RoleId == 1).Select(p => p.Permissions).ToList();
var getAllPermissionGroup = context.PermissionGroups.ToList();

List<PermissionGroup> jsonPg = new List<PermissionGroup>();

foreach (var pg in getAllPermissionGroup)
{
    PermissionGroup newPg = new PermissionGroup();
    newPg.PermissionGroupId = pg.PermissionGroupId;
    newPg.PermissionGroupName = pg.PermissionGroupName;
    newPg.Permissons = new List<Permission>();

    foreach (var pers in getPermissionsForRole[0])
    {
        if (pers.PermissionGroup.PermissionGroupId == pg.PermissionGroupId)
        {
            Permission newPe = new Permission();
            newPe.PermissionId = pers.PermissionId;
            newPe.PermissionName = pers.PermissionName;

            newPg.Permissons.Add(newPe);
        }
    }

    if (newPg.Permissons.Count > 0)
    {
        jsonPg.Add(newPg); 
    }
}

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonPg);
```

Still open to better code.

Comment: It is not that efficient because you make 2 queries which is worst than 1 query. I believe you can do it in 1 query.

Comment: Not to mention that is one ugly code. Thanks for your help. You saved me from a lot of bad practice.

Comment: You are welcome! I want also say that despite this code is not perfect, it is great that you are trying to do somehting, trying to find workaround (and you actually did!). It is very good side of your character.